# Detecting xSocket connection loss in client

Tags: javascript, xsockets.net, xsocket

This is for Xsockets.

I have a client connected to a socket, lets say the client looses internet connection, is there a xSocket function that will get called on the client that will let me know that the client (itself) is not connected to the socket anymore?

Currently, im just getting a error:

WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

I know that the socket itself knows that the client is disconnected, but how can the client know that its diconnected?

The XSockets.Events.onError and XSockets.Events.close functions are not called.

PS: Im running 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The  XSockets.Events.close should fire when the connection i lost ( client calls .close ) or server shutsdown the binding / subscription fires. XSockets.Events.close .

```
ws.bind(XSockets.Events.close, function(reason) { });
```

Try call .close method to validate if the event fires

```
ws.close()
```

Anyway, you have some code to share?

I also recommend you to upgrate to 3.0.6 the latest version of generation 3 of XSockets.NET . I would also concider haveing a look at generation 4.